# How to go about changing public keys of a user in my web3 app?

Tags: ethereum

Based on my understanding [social wallet](https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/01/11/recovery.html), from the point of view of a web3 app, the user's ID should not be their public key (cause that can be changed by guardians). Is this correct?

If so, a web3 app would have to have its own internal userId for each user which is mapped to their current public key. In case the public key changes (cause the guardians change the private key), then this mapping would need to change too somehow.

Is there any literature about how this change can be made from the web3 app developer's point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Based on my understanding social wallet, from the point of view of a web3 app, the user's ID should not be their public key

Your understanding is incorrect. The public key / address is the id of the user.

Comment: In that case, if an app uses their public key in all it's application tables, but if the user wants to change their public key (cause the private key is stolen), then all of that user's info in the app will be stuck with their older public key.

Comment: That's correct. Then it is s a support issue, not an issue that should be resolved automatically. If the private key is stolen it is game over for the user any case. It is the  responsibility of the user to keep their private keys private and if they do not do that then they should not use private keys in the first place.

Comment: Understoof., However, the point of a social wallet + a vault is that if a private key is stolen, the user has a certain time period during which they can reverse transactions (cause of the vault), and also get their guardians to change the private key used to access the vault. So in that way, it's not really game over.

Comment: Because the wallet is smart contract based, not direct private/public key, you can change the keys of the smart contract without changing the address itself.